# Determine if internet connection is available

Tags: sencha-touch, internet-connection

how do you folks check if the device is connected to the internet in a sencha touch app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an attribute called `navigator.onLine` (general browser support, not specific for Sencha)

If I'm in a PhoneGap application (which you often are if you're using Sencha Touch), I'd rather use their [network.isReachable](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_network_network.md.html) function, since I've by experience found it more reliable.

There's also something called 'Offline events', John Resig describes them on his blog:  http://ejohn.org/blog/offline-events/.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no network connection during an ajax request sencha touch will return a response with a 0 status. So this is what we're using in our app (works in phonegap too):

```
// global error handling
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(connection, response) {
  // get rid of any loading masks that are present
  Ext.each(Ext.query('.x-mask'), function(el) {
      new Ext.Element(el).hide()
  });
  switch(response.status) {
    case 0 :
      Ext.Msg.alert('Error Loading', 'No Internet connection.');
      break;
    case 401 :
      Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed', 'Check your username and password.');
      break;
    default :
      Ext.Msg.alert('Whoops!', 'An unexpected error has occurred and we have been alerted.');
  }
});
```

Note that this is for touch 1.1, haven't tried in in 2.0 yet.