# How to detect the internet connection in sencha touch

Tags: networking, cordova, extjs

I have a small application based on Sencha touch. this application should submit data to the server lets say this is an example of Ajax call that I did

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://www.google.com',
timeout:30*1000,
success: function(response, opts) {
  console.dir('success');
},
failure: function(response, opts) {
  console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
}
```

Now the

> failure

never gets called if I have a network connection but without internet !! the problem that I have my client does not have a solid internet connection but he has a wifi all the time !
So , everything I found on the net detect if I have a Network connection ! but I already have one but this connection does not provide Internet.

anyone knows how to detect the Internet connection not the Network?

FYI : I tried the navigator.online and the network state examples all of them does not detect internet, also I attached a phoneGap listener since I'm using sencha with phoneGap to create a iOS app !

EDIT: I'm using Sencha v1.1

Comment: This?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728346/determine-if-internet-connection-is-available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert(Ext.device.Connection.isOnline());
```

Here's url, 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Connection

Answer (score 1):

You can also detect the connection using PhoneGap.  See:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: Ext.device.Connection is a simple wrapper and uses Phonegap, if for a packaged app. So Ext.device.Connection is prefered.

Answer (score 1):

If the success callback is being invoked, then you best check the response parameter for null and/or length.  If you find null or zero length, then assume the request failed.