# Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() and Ext.browser.is.WebView not working on Sencha Touch 2.0.1

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, cordova-2.0.0, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am working on an Android app with Sencha Touch, but Ext.device.Connection.getType() is always returning UNKNOWN for me. I have found a work around with the navigator.onLine function (from [Determine if internet connection is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728346/determine-if-internet-connection-is-available)). However I am a little alarmed that this basic functionality is not working as documented (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Connection). Looking into the source code (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/source/Connection2.html#Ext-device-Connection) I saw the Connection constructor checks Ext.browser.is.WebView and got curious. Running the following line logs a lot of seemingly incorrect information:

```
for (prop in Ext.browser.is) { console.log('Ext.browser.is.' + prop + ': ' + Ext.browser.is[prop]); }
```

For example:

```
Ext.browser.is.Safari: true
Ext.browser.is.WebView: false
Ext.browser.is.webview: false
```

Are these Ext.browser.is properties wrong? It seems the Ext.browser.is properties could cause a lot of other issues in my app and Connection.isOnline is just a symptom of a deeper issue. Is there a specific technique or code for getting Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() to work?

If got 'Ext.device.Device' & 'Ext.device.Connection' in my apps' requirements and the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I am using Sencha Touch 2.0.1 (with PhoneGap/Cordova 2.2.0) & testing device is Samsung Stratosphere (with Android 2.3.6)